# Retrieving data from Firebase with Android not working properly

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to obtain the current user's details by doing so:

```
Constants.USER_REF.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         if (dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot != null) {
             // User exists at this point, store it as currentUser variable.
             User currentUser = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

             Log.i("THE_SNAPSHOT_AS_STRING:::", dataSnapshot.toString());

             // GETTING THE ERROR ON THE LINE BELOW!
             Log.i("THE_USERS_EMAIL:::", currentUser.getEmail());

         } else {
             // User does not exist at this point.
             Toast.makeText(TourContactActivity.this, "No user exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
      }
      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

      }
});
```

I also get the following printed in the console log, so I know it's pulling in the proper user.

```
07-13 15:16:18.391 32277-32277/thepassapp.thompson.com.tomstours I/THE_SNAPSHOT_AS_STRING:::: DataSnapshot { key = users, value = {00845752-985f-4779-8eff-0c1e6a016ad8={tour_director_key=70af128e-777b-4c12-86f6-2952dbdc9185, last_name=River, email=rivers@gmail.com, location_latitude=42.4305, tour_id=n1337e, photo=http://chopu.herokuapp.com/parse/files/2enxs2j21mz9/7304a8917568d366a8ec43f5ab88ac6b_user.jpg, tour_director_name=Chuck Thoms, middle_name=, location_longitude=-73.5103, passenger_id=mcu79, location_updated=1468360656387, tour_director=f9e3z, first_name=Gene, provider=password}} }
```

Here is my User.class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)

public class User {

    private String uid;
    private String email;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;

    public User() {

        // empty default constructor, necessary for Firebase to be able to deserialize users

    }
    public User(String uid, String first_name, String last_name, String email) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return first_name;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return last_name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{uid='"+uid+"', email='"+email+"', first_name='"+first_name+"', last_name='"+last_name+"\'}";

    }

}
```

My problem is actually retrieving this data from the User class. I followed the docs, but keep getting the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: passengerapp.veriguide.com.veriguidetours, PID: 32277
java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Note: I commented the line I'm obtaining the error on.

Comment: looks like `getEmail()` is returning null, can you share your database structure?

Comment: As you see in my Log.i it prints the proper users data and email is included in it

Comment: The User class is what I created to hold the database structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly call `getValue()` because the dataSnapshot has childs, so you need to iterate the child before getting the value.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            User currentUser = data.getValue(User.class);
            Log.i("THE_SNAPSHOT_AS_STRIN", data.toString());
            Log.i("THE_USERS_EMAIL:::", currentUser.getEmail());
        }
    } else {
        // User does not exist at this point.
    }
}
```

And also, you have to create setter for your `User` class so the value can be set to the class.

```
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}
public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}
...
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Current User can be obtained by

```
  FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        userEmail = user.getEmail();
        userName = user.getDisplayName();
}
```

Comment: That's the Firebase user itself, I'm looking to obtain the data I write manually to /users if you look at the query above. It's logging the correct user as shown above as well, it's just returning null when trying to call the get methods on the class.

Comment: Can you upload a snapshot of your Firebase DB?