# Why I can not read and display data from Firebase real-time database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to develop an android which is read and display data from Firebase database, unfortunately, I could not able to display any data from the database.There are no error messages or any error issues are noted in Android monitor(I am using Android Studio).The only issue I noticed which is in FriendlyMessage file setText,setName,setPhotoUrl this three methods are never used.

There are three parts of the project, 1)mainactivity,2)MessageAdapter,3)Friendlymessage
1)MaiinActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;

private ListView mMessageListView;
private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
private EditText mMessageEditText;
private Button mSendButton;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
private ChildEventListener monchildlistner;
private String mUsername;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

    mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("message");


    // Initialize references to views
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mMessageListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
    mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
    mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);


    // Initialize message ListView and its adapter
    List<FriendlyMessage> friendlyMessage = new ArrayList<>();
    mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this, R.layout.item_message,friendlyMessage);
    mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);

    // Initialize progress bar
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);

    // ImagePickerButton shows an image picker to upload a image for a message
    mPhotoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO: Fire an intent to show an image picker
        }
    });

    // Enable Send button when there's text to send
    mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }
    });
    mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});

    // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO: Send messages on click
      FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage=new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
             mFirebaseDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
            // Clear input box
            mMessageEditText.setText("");
        }
    });
    monchildlistner=new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            FriendlyMessage friendlymessage=dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
            mMessageAdapter.add(friendlymessage);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
       //when a message added on the database at that time addchildeventlistener will fire up and refer us to onchildadded method
    mFirebaseDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(monchildlistner);

}
```

}
 2)MessageAdapter:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FriendlyMessage>{
public MessageAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FriendlyMessage> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_message, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView photoImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photoImageView);
    TextView messageTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
    TextView authorTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);

    FriendlyMessage message = getItem(position);

    boolean isPhoto = message.getPhotoUrl() != null;
    if (isPhoto) {
        messageTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        photoImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Glide.with(photoImageView.getContext())
                .load(message.getPhotoUrl())
                .into(photoImageView);
    } else {
        messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        photoImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        messageTextView.setText(message.getText());
    }
    authorTextView.setText(message.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

}
3)FriendlyMessage:

```
public class FriendlyMessage {
private String text;
private String name;
private String photoUrl;

public FriendlyMessage() {
}

public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
    this.text = text;
    this.name = name;
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return photoUrl;
}

public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is your method that tries to access Firebase?

Comment: private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;

mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mFirebaseDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("message");

Comment: You need to post the whole method, including the onDataChange method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving data from Firebase with Android not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38360070/retrieving-data-from-firebase-with-android-not-working-properly)

Comment: Can you share your database structure from Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

After you add your message, you are not notifying the adapter to refresh or load the content that is newly added.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

would work

Comment: By the way, I did it by call addchildlistener.

Comment: would you be able to see your messages in firebase database?

Comment: Yes, write to Firebase is perfect.

Comment: i have gone through your code, there is no adapter notifier as you mentioned. After mMessageAdapter.add(friendlymessage); add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I also see you are adding it to adapter, add the element to list and notify the adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148640/discussion-between-jay-and-user3728517).

Comment: I noticed one issue which is setter methods is not worked in friendlychat app, the issue says that setText,photourl is never used.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the issue and the problem was solved, I am going to mark this topic as a solved issue.The problem was in my layout file.Unfortunately, I was assigned the list view value '0', after changed the value '0' to match parent it's working fine.Thanks everyone for your support.